# Дискорд бот не выдаёт роли (Пайтон)

Tags: python, discord.py

При попытке получить роль путём установки реакции, бот выдаёт ошибку: [ERROR] KeyError, no role found for 
помогите пожалуйста

основной код:
import discord
from discord import utils

import config

class MyClient(discord.Client):
async def on_ready(self):
print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))

```
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    if payload.message_id == config.POST_ID:
        channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id) # получаем объект канала
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) # получаем объект сообщения
        member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id) # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию

        try:
            emoji = str(payload.emoji) # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
            role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji]) # объект выбранной роли (если есть)
        
            if(len([i for i in member.roles if i.id not in config.EXCROLES]) <= config.MAX_ROLES_PER_USER):
                await member.add_roles(role)
                print('[SUCCESS] User {0.display_name} has been granted with role {1.name}'.format(member, role))
            else:
                await message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, member)
                print('[ERROR] Too many roles for user {0.display_name}'.format(member))
        
        except KeyError as e:
            print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))

async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
    channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id) # получаем объект канала
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) # получаем объект сообщения
    member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id) # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию

    try:
        emoji = str(payload.emoji) # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
        role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji]) # объект выбранной роли (если есть)

        await member.remove_roles(role)
        print('[SUCCESS] Role {1.name} has been remove for user {0.display_name}'.format(member, role))

    except KeyError as e:
        print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
```

client = MyClient()
client.run(config.TOKEN)

дополнительный код:
TOKEN = '(тут токен стоял)'

POST_ID = 842360110650884096

ROLES = {
':video_game:': 842354678024241162, #GAMER
':computer:': 842354808739332119, #DARU-ITARU
':u6e80:': 842354912272842843, #NYA
}

EXCROLES = {}

MAX_ROLES_PER_USER = 5

Answer (score 1):

Написал код на `получение/удаление` роли при клике на реакцию

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        message_id = payload.message_id
        if message_id == message_id:
            guild_id = payload.guild_id
            guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == guild_id, self.bot.guilds)

            channel = self.bot.get_channel(channel_id)
            msg = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)

            if payload.emoji.id == emoji_id:
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=role_id)
                await msg.remove_reaction('<:emoji_namea:emoji_id>', self.bot.get_user(payload.user_id))

            else:
                pass

            member = discord.utils.get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)
            if role != None:
                if member != None:
                    if role not in member.roles:
                        await member.add_roles(role)
                    else:
                        await member.remove_roles(role)

            else:
                print(f'Role {role} not found')
```